# Problemas con conexión Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

quisiera saber si pueden apoyarme, tengo este problema, es un sistema que ya está montado y ha estado asi y sirviendo sin ningún problema, pero desde esta semana, me ha estado dando problemas y no logro resolverlo, el detalle es que es un sistema que no hice, pero tengo que darle mantenimiento, el cual antes no pasaba de solamente levantar el servidor con runserver, pero ahora me muestra el siguiente mensaje.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

gracias de antemano

Comment: Recordá que no todos pueden visualizar las imágenes, por lo tanto los mensajes de error y código deben ir _como texto con formato_. Por otra parte, ¿viste [esta pregunta](/q/145831)?

Comment: @Alfabravo, me dio una idea, pero todavía tendría que ver como encuentro qué afectó para poder ver cómo resolverlo, pero practicamente creo que según entendí no es pobrema de python, sino de problemas de seguridad (siempre con la app, pero tengo que ver que causa que piense que son ataques)

Comment: EL camino es revisar qué cambió. Nuevo firewall? Nuevo antivirus? Nuevo equipo de seguridad en la red y las peticiones pasan a través de él (un IDP, un WAF)?